# Tamely ramified extension of local fields

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory, local-field

I am trying to understand the tamely ramified extensions of a local field. First of all, when would be two such extensions $L_1/K$ and $L_2/K$ over the same base field be isomorphic? Second, for totally ramified extensions of local fields $L/K,$ there is a result that says the extension can be written as a tower of of extensions $K \subset K^{\textrm ur} \subset L$ where $K^{\textrm ur}$ is the maximal unramified extension of $K$. Is there a similar result for tamely ramified? (i.e., a totally ramified extension $L/K$ with an intermediate field, say $T$, such that $T/K$ is the maximal tamely ramified)? If there is, would $T$ be unique?

Comment: Shouldn't $K^{ur}=K$ if $L/K$ is totally ramified?

Comment: Also, $L_1/K$ and $L_2/K$ would be isomorphic in the usual sense, i.e., there exists a ring isomorphism $\tau\colon L_1\to L_2$ fixing $K$.

Comment: The tower of extensions comes from the tower of Galois groups $1\subset I\subset G$, where $I$ is the inertia group. To get the maximal tamely ratified extension, just throw in $I_w\subset I$, the wild inertia group.

Comment: @KentaS right, I am asking for conditions which would make the isomorphism exist.

Comment: A tamely ramified extension $L$ of degree $n$ over a $p$-adic field $K$ is defined by taking the $n$-th root of a uniformizer $u$ of $K$. So the bijection is between the $L$ and the  $uO_K^{\times n}$. By Hensel, $O_K^{\times n}$ is the set of elements who are $n$-th powers in the residue field $k$, so that (for instance) the number of tamely ramified extensions of $K$ of degree $n$ should be exactly the cardinality of $k^{\times}/k^{\times n}$.

Comment: @Aphelli do you have a reference you can suggest?

Comment: https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~pierre.colmez/CL.pdf are pretty good notes (in French) for “elementary” Galois theory of $p$-adic fields. All of it should also be in Serre’s *Local Fields*.